# Printing complete then change default printer in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, printing, wait, jobs

i'm having a problem and maybe somebody can help me.

I'm trying to print a document using the printdocument class.
This works and it's printing 2 documents.
After the printer is done printing i must print another document (website) to a different printer.
I don't think there is a way to simultaneously print this.
So what i'm doing is: Set the default printer to printer 1. then i must wait till both (varies) documents are completed. Then change the default printer to 2. Send the command and print on printer 2.

This is the code i have currently:

```
 <DllImport("winspool.drv", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True)>
    Public Shared Function SetDefaultPrinter(name As String) As Boolean
    End Function

'set default printer1
PrintDocument_BO.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = Printer1

  Dim jobnumbernotnull = False
'wait for jobs
  While Not jobnumbernotnull
          pq.Refresh()
          jobnumbernotnull = pq.NumberOfJobs > 0
  End While



 Dim jobs = pq.GetPrintJobInfoCollection()
'wait till all jobs are completed
    For Each job In jobs
       Dim done = False

          While Not done

            pq.Refresh()
            job.Refresh()
            done = job.IsCompleted OrElse job.IsDeleted OrElse job.IsPrinted

          End While
     Next

'set default printer2
 SetDefaultPrinter(Printer2)
 DefaultPrinter = "Printer2"
```

But when i run this: Printer1 is default and one document is printing.
it doesn't wait till the document is completed and just sets printer2 as default, then switches back to printer1 and prints everything on printer1.

So my questions are: Is it possible to print a printdocument to 1 printer and simultaneously print a website on printer2?

And, how can i wait for the first printer to be completely done printing so i can switch the default printers?
I've also tried using the printer Jobstatus but nothing seems to work.
Thank you!

Comment: Could you send the print job to a specific printer instead of the default printer?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.printersettings), it should be sufficient to set the value of `PrinterSettings.PrinterName` - there is no need to set the default printer.

Comment: I'm setting the printername in my code using: PrintDocument_BO.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = Printer1. This still changes the default printer. I'm using this because the first document i print is using the printdocument class. But the second print in do is a website, i don't think i can use PrinterSettings.PrinterName printing a website.

Comment: You can't print on the client printer from server-side code, if that is what you mean by website.

Comment: Yes, i'm using a WebView2 control and i don't believe you can use PrinterSettings.PrinterName with that.